# android 2.1 rotate cause crash

Tags: android

After months of developing I realize that my app (only using android 2.1) crashes when I rotate screen. I don't know how investigate about this error. What should be the cause? Thanks for advices. Can this "warning" cause error? Unexpected resume of com.example.app while already resumed in com.example.app

```
SharedPreferences prefs3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {       
                preferenze();





E/AndroidRuntime( 1269): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.util.HashMap.doubleCapacity(HashMap.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.<init>(Charset.java:189)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.ibm.icu4jni.charset.CharsetICU.<init>(CharsetICU.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.ibm.icu4jni.charset.CharsetProviderICU.getCharset(CharsetProviderICU.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.ibm.icu4jni.charset.CharsetProviderICU.charsetForName(CharsetProviderICU.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forNameInternal(Charset.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.setOutput(FastXmlSerializer.java:292)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl.writeFileLocked(ApplicationContext.java:2757)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(ApplicationContext.java:2510)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:3632)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(MainActivity.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ApplicationContext.java:2703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    at com.example.app.MainActivity.preferenze(MainActivity.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1269):    a
```

Comment: Please provide some code for mentioned lines in `MainActivity`.

Comment: 3000lines of code. Tell me which part of this. thanks

Comment: Is com.example.app the name of your app? If so it looks like you're doing something in onSharedPreferenceChanged that's causing an infinite loop, which eventually eats up enough memory to cause a stack overflow. Maybe you've got a line inside of onSharedPreferenceChanged that causes onSharedPreferenceChanged to be called again indirectly?

Comment: yes. I've a "preferenze()" method that reads preferences from sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `preferenze` routine in your MainActivity.java.

Would need to see some more code to be sure, but it appears you have an infinite recursion caused by modifying your `Preferences` inside a `onSharedPreferenceChanged` callback.  If you edit your preferences in the callback, the callback gets invoked again, then you edit again, the callback gets invoked again, etc, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure is infinite recursive. The listener check only when I open "setting" on my app.

Comment: reading is fine, writing is the problem.  Hard to put finger exactly on the problem without seeing the code, but at line 3732 you are causing the preferences to be written (via `commit`) and that causes the listener to be called again.

Comment: That I cannot say for sure.  I